# Upload An Excel File From My Woocommerce Site After Payment Completed to A Site That Doesn't Have API

Tags: wordpress, api, curl, woocommerce

Guys is it possible to send order details from my woocommerce site" to this partner site that doesn't have or provide API.
I've been doing it manually for over a year now and i want to see if its possible to automate things.
The partner sends OTP code to your phone right after you've entered your password and click submit then when OTP is verified and logged in i visit this page that has just an upload form and a submit button, I then upload the excel file and click on the submit then voila done.

I got the example below from GPT :

```
// Get order details
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$billing_email  = $order->get_billing_email();  // Customer email
$order_number  = $order->get_order_number();   // Order number

// Form values to send
$data = array(
    'email' => $billing_email,
    'order_num' => $order_number,
);

// URL of the other site to send data
$url = 'https://example.com/submit-form.php'; 

// Login credentials for the other site
$auth_username = 'username'; 
$auth_password = 'password'; 
    
// Create a session on the other site
$session = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'/login.php'); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$auth_username&password=$auth_password"); 
$html = curl_exec($session); 
curl_close($session);

// Send the form data 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'/submit-form.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

}
```